# Cause of Data format 'pgp' could not be created. Ensure that the data format is valid and the associated Camel component is present on the classpath

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

I am working toward processing pgp encrypted batch files.  I am trying to experiment with using Camel to decrypt a pgp encrypted file within a Spring Boot application.  My simple route currently results in the following error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Data format 'pgp' could
>   not be created. Ensure that the data format is valid and the
>   associated Camel component is present on the classpath

My Route:

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("sftp://localhost/INBOUND?username=blah&password=foo&delay=10000")
            .unmarshal().pgp("/opt/keys/batchkeys/secring.gpg", null, "thePassword")
            .to("file:{{route.to}}");
}
```

My maven pom dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-ftp-starter</artifactId>
        <version>2.18.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-crypto-starter</artifactId>
        <version>2.18.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Apache Camel internally will refer BOUNCY CASTLE libraries to encrypt or decrypt for PGP key.

Please try to add below two dependencies and give a try,
bcprov-ext-jdk15on and bcprov-jdk15on